# Service Account for Google Data Studio to Access HTML Files on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-storage, looker-studio, service-accounts

I have some HTML files uploaded into a Google Cloud Storage bucket that I would like to embed through an iframe on my dashboard in Google Data Studio.

This works just fine when I open access to the world on the bucket (or resource) by setting the `AllUsers` permission.

However, I would prefer to only allow access through Google Data Studio. How can this be achieved?

I was thinking of adding a permission for the Service Account of Google Data Studio, but don't really know how to configure this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible right now.

However, a complex solution I can think of is to use a combination of Community Connectors and Community Viz:

- [Build a community connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started) that uses your own GCP service account to read the HTML files on GCS and send back the raw HTML content as data.
- [Build a community viz](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/get-started) that can take the HTML data from the connector and render the HTML.
- If you have multiple HTML files, you can setup filters in Data Studio so that each viz renders only one HTML.

Code samples for Community Connector and viz are available [here](https://github.com/googledatastudio/).